# Ruby Rspec csv parser syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')

Tags: ruby, rspec

Hello friends I am new to Ruby Rspec

I am testing a Ruby Rspec csv parser  for csv manipulation with

```
describe "bashing outing the strings" do
  it " inputs" do
    expect(guess_csv("100,24,32\n42,52,62", ",", "\"")).to eq([["100", "24", "32"], ["42", "52", "62"]])
  end
```

and ruby.rb

````
def parse_csv(csv, separator, quote)
 final_array = []
  lines = ("100,24,32\n42,52,62", ",", "\"",  quote: "'", separator: ",").split(/\,\n/).map(&:parse_csv) do |line|
  line.split(',')
   final_array << line.scan(/\,\n/)
  end
  final_array 
end```



An error occurred while loading spec_helper.
Failure/Error: require 'solution'
````

An error occurred while loading spec_helper.
Failure/Error: require 'servertime'

SyntaxError:
/chicago/default/lib/servertime.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...lines = ("100,24,32\n42,52,62", ",", """,  quote: "'", sepa...
...                              ^
/chicago/default/lib/servertime.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
... = ("100,24,32\n42,52,62", ",", """,  quote: "'", separator...
...                              ^
/chicago/default/lib/servertime.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...00,24,32\n42,52,62", ",", """,  quote: "'", separator: ",")...
...                              ^
/chicago/default/lib/servertime.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...52,62", ",", """,  quote: "'", separator: ",").split(/,\n/...
...                              ^
/chicago/default/lib/servertime.rb:6: both block arg and actual block given

## ./spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `require'

## ./spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

No examples found.
No examples found.

```
Just wondering how to fix it
```

Comment: `("100,24,32\n42,52,62", ",", "\"",  quote: "'", separator: ",")` is not a valid Ruby expression. What do you try to achieve in that line? Do you want to create an array? But an array would not support calling `split`. Or should this be a list of arguments send to a method and the method name is missing?

Comment: @spickermann thanks for the response.

The expected result is : Array within array  that is : [["100", "24", "32"], ["42", "52", "62"]]

There is a method : def parse_csv(csv, separator, quote) with the method name  : parse_csv
with a list of arguments

Comment: Which of the two files you posted is `servertime.rb`?

Comment: @user1934428
The servertime.rb file is :
```
def parse_csv(csv, separator, quote)
 final_array = []
  lines = ("100,24,32\n42,52,62", ",", "\"",  quote: "'", separator: ",").split(/\,\n/).map(&:parse_csv) do |line|
  line.split(',')
   final_array << line.scan(/\,\n/)
  end
  final_array 
end```

Comment: The issue is :
```
SyntaxError:
  /workspace/default/lib/servertime.rb: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
    ("100,24,32\n42,52,62", ",", "\"").split(',')
                   ^
  /workspace/default/lib/servertime.rb: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
    ("100,24,32\n42,52,62", ",", "\"").split(',')
 ```